# Tilemap platform collision detection with Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm getting my feet wet with game development by working on a platformer using Cocos2d for iPhone. I'm struggling a bit in getting collision detection running so that my character will have his jump action cancelled when he hits a platform.

I'm using a technique from [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1186/collisions-and-collectables-how-to-make-a-tile-based-game-with-cocos2d-part-2) where I create a separate layer of "meta tiles". The problem is that collision detection does not occur until the character sprite is well within the collidable tile, not on top of it.

I'm using the code below to determine the tile coordinate based on my character sprite's current position:

```
    - (CGPoint) tileCoordForPosition: (CGPoint) position {
    int x = position.x / tileMap.tileSize.width;
    int y = ((tileMap.mapSize.height * tileMap.tileSize.height) - position.y) / tileMap.tileSize.height;
    return ccp(x, y);
}
```

I tried various techniques, even trying to figure out what tile was below my character using this code:

```
- (void) update: (ccTime) dt {
    BOOL isCollision = NO;
    if (firstRun) {
        oldY = player.position.y;
        firstRun = NO;
    }
    CGPoint oneTileDown = ccp(player.position.x, player.position.y / 2);
    CGPoint tileCoord = [gameplayLayer tileCoordForPosition:oneTileDown];
    int tileGid = [gameplayLayer.meta tileGIDAt:tileCoord];

    if (tileGid) {
        NSDictionary* tileProperties = [gameplayLayer.tileMap propertiesForGID:tileGid];
        if (tileProperties) {
            NSString* collision = [tileProperties valueForKey:@"Collidable"];
            if (collision && [collision compare:@"True"] == NSOrderedSame) {
                //CCLOG(@"Collision Below");
                isCollision = YES;
                if (player.characterState == kStateFalling) {
                    [player stopAllActions];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (oldY < player.position.y) {
        CCLOG(@"Character is jumping");
        player.characterState = kStateJumping;
    }
    else if (oldY > player.position.y) {
        CCLOG(@"Character is falling");
        player.characterState = kStateFalling;
    }

    oldY = player.position.y;
}
```

But the same problem happens: my character jumps, lands inside of the collision tile and is stopped instead of landing on top of the tile.

Is there a better way of checking for collision in a tilemap?

Comment: Do you remember what solution did u use?

Comment: Hi James, I'm in the very same situation that you were when you posted this question. Do you have any solution that you'd be willing to share? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution to this issue.

In the method `(CGPoint) tileCoordForPosition: (CGPoint)` position you have to write the following:

```
int x = position.x / tileMap.tileSize.width;
    int y = ((tileMap.mapSize.height * tileMap.tileSize.height + player.contenSize().height / 2) - position.y) / tileMap.tileSize.height;
    return ccp(x, y);
```

`player` is a sprite from which you have to add half its height.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use `CGRectContainRect` to check if the player sprite's bounding box is intersecting with and of the tiles where it shouldn't.